# Why TYPO3 have a wrong path on macOS 10.14

Tags: php, macos, path, typo3

I have a fresh install of TYPO3 9.5.24 with Apache and PHP 7.2.34 on macOS Mojave.

After i call the site i'll get this warning:

```
Warning: require(/Volumes/Daten/htdocs/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Volumes/Daten/htdocs/typo3_sourcen/typo3_src-9.5.24/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php on line 92
```

As you can see, the path to 'ConfigurationManager.php' is right, but then it's looking for 'DefaultConfiguration.php' in a wrong path. It should be

```
/Volumes/Daten/htdocs/typo3_sourcen/typo3_src-9.5.24/typo3/
```

instead of

```
/Volumes/Daten/htdocs/typo3/
```

How can i solve this Problem?

This is how i setup (but it's not my very first instance of TYPO3) using .zip:

1. Make Symlinks to the needed folders and files in the target directory:

ln -s /Volumes/Daten/htdocs/typo3_sourcen/typo3_src-9.5.24 ./typo3_src

ln -s ./typo3_src/typo3/ ./typo3

ln -s ./typo3/index.php ./

and call the site via browser.

Edit:

Found the mistake:

instead of

```
ln -s ./typo3/index.php ./
```

it should be

```
ln -s ./typo3_src/index.php ./
```

Comment: It seems you chose the install via .tar.gz. this requires some symlinks. Can you share how you have set them up? (`ls -als`)

Comment: Edited my post...

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. Please mark the question as resolved.

Comment: @ThomasSchulze make an own answer from your last edit, then mark it as solution.

Comment: Actually it is safer to use file symlink like `ln -s ./typo3_src/index.php ./index.php` you don't need to rely on index resolving in such case.